# php calculation with decimal(10,3) results in exponential sometimes

Tags: php, precision, floating-accuracy

In my php script I do a calculation of entries from a MySQL db. The concerning fields in the db are defined as `decimal(10,3)`. It's an accounting plattform where I have to check if in every entry debit = credit.

I do this with the following operation:

```
$sumupNet = 0;
$sumup = 0;
foreach($val['Record'] as $subkey => $subval)
{
    $sumupNet = $sumupNet + $subval['lc_amount_net'];
    $sumup = $sumup + $subval['lc_amount_debit'] - $subval['lc_amount_credit'];
}
```

Now we say every entry is correkt, then $sumupNet and $sumup results in `0`. In most cases, this works. But in some cases the result is something like this: `-1.4432899320127E-15` or this `-8.8817841970013E-15`. If I calculate this values manually, the result is `0`. I guess (not sure) that the above results are numbers near 0 and are outputted in the form of exponential.

So I think I have to convert something or my calculation is wrong. But what? I tried floatval() at some points but didn't work. If anybody has a hint, I thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting this because you are doing math with floating-point values. [Read some theory about it](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

You really don't want to calculate money like that as you might get weird rounding problems that you can't really do anything to fix.

For PHP, there are plenty of libraries that help you evade the problem, such as [BC Math](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php), or [GMP](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php).

Other solution would be to calculate all of the values using the smallest monetary value that the currency has (like cents) so you are always using integers.

Comment: Thank you Andrius. I read the first paragraphs and flow over the rest of the document. I understood the main point. I change my numbers into integers.

Answer (score 0):

These are rounding problems. These are perfectly normal when we are talking about floats. To give you an everyday example,

1/3 = 0.3333333333333333...333333333...3333...

Reason: 10 is relative prime with 3. You might wonder where is 10 coming from. We are using 10-base for numbers, that is, whenever we speak about a number, its digits represent 10-base exponential values. The computer works with binary numbers, that is, 2-base numbers. This means that division with such numbers often result in endless sequences of digits. For instance, 1/3 as a binary number looks like this:

0.010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101...

Decimal types are representing decimal numbers, that is, 10-base numbers. You use three digits for the part after the . Let's supose your number ends like this:

.xyz

this means:

xyz / 1000

However, 1000 can be divided with the following prime numbers:

2 and 5.

Since 5 is relative prime with 2, whenever you are representing the result of a division by 5 as a binary number, there is a potential that the result will be an endless cycle of digits. 1/5 as a binary number looks like this:

0.0011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011...

Since a computer cannot store endless digits, it has to round the number, that is, find a number close to its value which can be represented in an easier manner. If the number a is rounded to b and the two numbers are not equal, then a certain amount of precision is lost and this is the reason of the bug you have mentioned.

You can solve the problem as follows: when you select the values from the database, multiply them by 1000 (thus, converting them into integers) and then check the operations. At the end, divide by 1000.

Comment: Thank you. I think your answer is too simple. Because my calculations are only plus and minus. So I wouldn't have any rounding issues. But the answer is way more complex as you find under the link Andrius postet above.

Comment: @FishWave, something being "too simple" as a statement is not a very high level. Decimal numbers are converted into binary numbers. Do you REALLY believe that in the process there are no divisions???